# JAXB XML Marshalling Object Only, but Unmarshalling Requires Full Structure?

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am using the standard JAXB API to work with XML. I need to marshal and then un-marshal an object (so the result should be the same object). I first marshal into a string, and then do the opposite -- unmarshal from a string into an object.

The problem is that Marshaller.marshal(obj,os) is giving me the **child only** (enclosed in XML). When I try to unmarshal back, I get errors about **missing parent tags** that are expected.

E.g.
(1) Marshalled String for the object "FieldSet":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FIELD1>field1</FIELD1>
<FIELD2>field2</FIELD2>
```

(2) Attempt to unmarshal this XML string into a "FieldSet" object:

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: tag name "FIELD1" is not allowed. Possible tag names are: 
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.msv.verifier.ValidityViolation: tag name "FIELD1" is not allowed. Possible tag names are: "Parent"]

In the schema, "Parent" is the top-level element that should precede "FieldSet".

Why are these standard JAXB operations not symmetrical, and what do I need to do synchronize them and avoid the child-only/missing parent issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To supply the root element information you can do one of the following:

1 - Annotate the class that you are annotating with `@XmlRootElement`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class FieldSet {
}
```

2 - Wrap the object you are marshalling with an instance of `JAXBElement`

```
QName qName = new QName("root");
JAXBElement<FieldSet> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<FieldSet>(qName, FieldSet.class, fieldSet);
```

Comment: I don't have access to JAXB classes, they are generated automatically. I am only working with objects. Should I annotate my instances?

Comment: @geneb if you don't want to annotate your instances you can use the `JAXBElement` approach instead.

Comment: When I try to wrap the object with JAXBElement, this exception happens:
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException: the object parameter to marshal() is not marshallable

Comment: @geneb. - The following example may help:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: The problem is not marshalling, it is unmarshalling. I can't seem to unmarshal an object that does not have XmlRootElement. However, I can't add it manually because our source code gets generated on the fly, and JAXB for some reason didn't mark this class as XmlRootElement. Is there a way to unmarshal the object (the reverse of what you gave) without XmlRootElement?

Comment: Yes, you can use one of the unmarshal methods that take a class parameter: `ummarshal(Source, Class)` or `unmarshal(XMLStreamReader, Class)`.  The input document will need a root element though.

Comment: Thanks! The above methods are not available in my JAXB library, Version 1.0.6. Were they added in 2.x?

Comment: @geneb. JAXB 1.0.6 is quite old, are you able to switch to a newer version.  A JAXB impl is included in the JDK/JRE starting with Java SE 6.